# How to add a Catch statement in this report snippet

Tags: java

Im running something like this:

```
    while (x <=6){
        System.out.println("Please select which example by its number.");
        System.out.println("1: example");
        System.out.println("2: example");
        System.out.println("3: example");
        System.out.println("4: example");
        System.out.println("5: Leave");
        }
```

---

What I want is to be able to catch if people try and type in letters/words over the number so what should I use instead of a `Ask = input.nextInt();` ??

Comment: Do you want to have a valid integer input? Because a catch clause makes no sense here.

Comment: Do you mean simply validate the input to check it's a valid option?

Comment: I don't understand the question.. Could you try to rephrase it a little?

Answer (score 0):

Check the isDigit () function:

```
public class Program {
public static void main(String[] args) {

char value1 = '9';
char value2 = 'Y';
char value3 = ' ';

// See if these characters are digits.
System.out.println(Character.isDigit(value1));
System.out.println(Character.isDigit(value2));
System.out.println(Character.isDigit(value3));
}
```

}

**Output**

```
     - true    
     - false
     - false
```

Comment: Not as straight if there are more than 10 options. I think it's just less boilerplate to simply use `Scanner.nextInt`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `Scanner.nextInt` and catch `NumberFormatException`. Not going to include the code because I think you should have researched more than this.